# "A 404 error occurred" in Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2.2, installation, nginx

magento project directory is located in `/var/www/html/site.com/public_html`.

After extracted in magento directory, I visited **site.com/magento**. That redirects to **site.com/magento/setup** and shows like this

[image]

Some basic information :

OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Server: Nginx, Magento version : 2.2.1

I am using magento as a **sub directory**.
Please comment what more information should I provide?

Comment: did you install magento?

Comment: I just download a tar.gz file. Uploaded it via FTP. Extracted it in the mentioned directory

Comment: you must want to install magento 2

Comment: Whats the process of instillation? I just kept the magento project directory. What next ?

Comment: Is there any installation button in link site.com/magento

Comment: No. This is the problem. No installation page is showing. http://findbook.link/magento

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72101/discussion-between-partho-and-jaimin).

Comment: one thing you can do is setup your magento2 in local first and then upload all file and database to server.

Comment: Consider to add the server error / access log. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324957/apache2-4-7-not-logging-404-not-found-pages-to-error-log?noredirect=1&lq=1